# How can i hide specific shipping method for specific customer group in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, shipping, frontend, backend

i want to make one custom module in that i set customer group and shipping method than that particulate customer group hide that shipping method
[image]
can any one help me how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shipping carrier class, there's a method to validate additional rules `proccessAdditionalValidation`, searching for that method in the code base will reveal `processAdditionalValidation` (less than 1 'c'). Then continue searching with that will lead `collectCarrierRates`

So in my opinion, there will be 2 approaches for this:

1. Extend the current Carrier, add logic into `proccessAdditionalValidation`
2. Make a new module, with GUI that helps customers/store-owner choose the rules and then process that rule inside `Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php:collectCarrierRates`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done something similar but as I checked the code right now, you can create an after Plugin for this method `\Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory::createIfActive` or also this method `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::isShippingCarrierAvailable`, there you can add your validation and return true or false for the shipping method you allow or not.

Although I haven't tried it yet, maybe it will guide you to the right direction.